# Display Closest Date Result Based on Another Date

Tags: sql, date

I have the below SQL query and I have discovered that there are multiple Consult, SIM, PLAN, TreatmentStart and TreatmentFinish results.

Using `MAX` only display the latest result, however I need say ,the Planning to display the closest most recent date previous to TreatmentStart, and SIM to display the closest most recent date previous to the Plan date.

With the start date being based on the most recent TreatmentStart date.

I am just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction because I wrote long winded sql queries that take more then 2 minutes to complete...

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT  s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, 
ShortDesc = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.Short_Desc END),
Consult = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '123'
                    AND s.SysDefStatus = 'C' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
SIM = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '456'
                      THEN s.App_DtTm END),
PLANNING = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '789'
                      THEN s.App_DtTm END),
TreatmentStart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
TreatmentFinished = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'FC' THEN s.App_DtTm END)
FROM    vw_Schedule s 
WHERE   s.Activity IN ('123', '456', '789')
OR      s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC', 'FC', 'C')
GROUP BY s.Pat_Name, s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1

)

SELECT  Pat_Name,
IDA,
Tx_Intent,
ShortDesc,
Consult,
Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, Consult, SIM)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, Consult, SIM)*2),
SIM,
Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, SIM, PLANNING)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, SIM, PLANNING)*2),
PLANNING,
Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, PLANNING, TreatmentStart)*2),
TreatmentStart,
Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)+1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinished)*2),
TreatmentFinished
FROM T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't you get the closest most recent date if you go for the MAX(dtmColumn) WHERE dtmColumn < dtmColumn2? This should give you the result with dtmColumn closest to dtmColumn2, but only the previous date obviously.

Seems like the most simple way to do it, however, I could imagine your case being too complex for something that simple to fix it.

Comment: I wish that were the case however the query only displays the MAX result because of the query itself :(

Comment: How about if you add this in the WHERE clause and simply get dtmColumn in the select:
`dtmColumn = (SELECT MAX(dtmColumn) FROM Table WHERE dtmColumn < dtmColumn2)`

Answer (score 0):

the below query is working as i want it to and displaying the correct results.

```
WITH PatCPlanRanked AS (
SELECT
Pat_ID1,
Tx_Intent,
Eff_DtTm,
Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pat_ID1 ORDER BY Eff_DtTm DESC)
FROM PatCPlan
),
T AS (
SELECT s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, s.Pat_Name, TreatmentStartDate = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
MAX(t.App_DtTm) AS PlanDate, MAX(u.App_DtTm) AS SIMDate, MAX(c.App_DtTm) AS ConsultDate,
ShortDesc = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.Short_Desc END), p.Tx_Intent,
Location = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.Location END)
FROM vw_Schedule s
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Schedule t
ON s.Pat_ID1 = t.Pat_ID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Schedule u
ON s.Pat_ID1 = u.Pat_ID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Schedule c
ON s.Pat_ID1 = c.Pat_ID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatCPlanRanked p
ON s.Pat_ID1=p.Pat_ID1 AND p.Ranking = 1

WHERE s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC') AND t.App_DtTm < s.App_DtTm AND u.App_DtTm < t.App_DtTm AND c.App_DtTm < u.App_DtTm 
AND t.Activity IN ('123')
AND u.Activity IN ('456') 
AND c.Activity IN ('789') 
AND c.SysDefStatus IN (' C') 
GROUP BY s.IDA, s.Pat_ID1, s.Pat_Name, p.Tx_Intent
)

SELECT  IDA, 
    Pat_Name,
    ShortDesc,
    Tx_Intent,
    Location,
    ConsultDate,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, ConsultDate, SimDate))-(DATEDIFF(wk, ConsultDate, SimDate)*2),
    SimDate,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, SimDate, PlanDate))-(DATEDIFF(wk, SimDate, PlanDate)*2),
    PlanDate,
    Days = (DATEDIFF(dd, PlanDate, TreatmentStartDate))-(DATEDIFF(wk, PlanDate, TreatmentStartDate)*2),
    TreatmentStartDate
FROM T
```

however the query takes about 35 seconds to complete can anyone give me any advice on how i can optimize this?

cheers guys